# named argument confusion in Rcpp-modules

Tags: r, package, rcpp

I want to create a package in R that uses cpp-code with the `Rcpp` package. In the cpp-code I need to use classes and member functions with named arguments. 
After building the package, functions inside of Rcpp-modules seem to be ignoring named inputs and parse by position instead.

For example using the `test` package, as described below, I get the following output

```r
# test the library
library(test)
# foo1 is a function outside of a module
foo1(a = "a", b = "b") # works as expected
#> a is a, b is b
foo1(b = "b", a = "a") # works as expected
#> a is a, b is b

# function within module "ABCMODULE"
foo2(a = "a", b = "b") # works as expected
#> a is a; b is b
foo2(b = "b", a = "a") # switches arguments <-------
#> a is b; b is a

abc <- new(ABC)
abc$foo3(a = "a", b = "b") # works as expected
#> a is a; b is b
abc$foo3(b = "b", a = "a") # switches arguments <-------
#> a is b; b is a
```

I have looked into the many Rcpp-vignettes but could find any solution to this. Have I overlooked something in the documents? Did I do a mistake somewhere? And how can I solve this or is this a feature/bug?

### Edit

On a similar note, when I try to set default values, i.e., `std::string b = "b"` in all code (updated below), the Rcpp-module-versions do not work when trying to use the default value (`foo1(a = "a")` results in `Error Expecting single string value` and `abc$foo3(a = "a")` results in `Error in ... could not find valid method`)

---

### `test` package

I have created the package with

`Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("test", module = T)`

then I added the two following files in `test/`

### added `src/foo1.cpp`

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void foo1(std::string a, std::string b = "b") {
  Rprintf("a is %s, b is %s", a.c_str(), b.c_str());
}
```

### added `src/ABC.cpp`

```cpp
// -*- mode: C++; c-indent-level: 4; c-basic-offset: 4; indent-tabs-mode: nil; -*-
#include <Rcpp.h>

void foo2(std::string a, std::string b = "b") {
    Rprintf("a is %s; b is %s\n", a.c_str(), b.c_str());
}

class ABC {
public:
  ABC() {}

  void foo3(std::string a, std::string b = "b");
};

void ABC::foo3(std::string a, std::string b) {
    Rprintf("a is %s; b is %s\n", a.c_str(), b.c_str());
}

RCPP_MODULE(ABCMODULE){
    using namespace Rcpp ;
    function("foo2" , &foo2  , "documentation for foo2");
    // with formal arguments specification
    class_<ABC>("ABC")
    // expose the default constructor
    .constructor()
    .method("foo3", &ABC::foo3 , "documentation for foo3")
    ;
}
```

### modified `R/zzz.R`

I added the following line to the bottom of the file

```r
loadModule("ABCMODULE", TRUE)
```

Comment: Hum, never seen anyone using Rcpp modules. Maybe, keeping the class in the R side would be easier?

Comment: F.Privé: please delete that comment.  There are a lots of packages on CRAN using Rcpp Modules, and have been for _many_ years.  If you didn't know, your problen.  Adds nothing to the OPs problem.

Comment: @David: There are limits to what Rcpp Modules can do with named arguments because we straddle R (for dispatch) and C++.  This is documented, see the vignette.   And see eg my [RcppAnnoy](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppannoy) for a reasonably complex use.